# How to throw exception with MessageBox in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, exception, async-await

I'm make an app which get data from API, but sometimes error will occur.

I have throw exception in my code when StatusCode is not Ok. But i have to handle it.

So, my question is how to get the exception on another thread and throw it with message box in xamarin.

```
ProductsNew = await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                ProductViewData productNewViewData = new ProductViewData();
                return productNewViewData.GetProductNew("5");
            });
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Put your code in try and catch block and show the error on message box.

```
try
{
//code
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   DisplayAlert("Error",ex.Message,"Ok");
}
```